# Fatal error with wp-livechat plugin

Tags: wp-query

Our website grantandgreen.de ask us to update 3 plugins one of which was wp-livechat, immediately after this our site crashed with the pasted message from our website

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_rest_url() in /homepages/25/d77035516/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wp-live-chat-support/modules/node_server.php on line 585

Since then when ever I login I only get this message and cannot return to the dashboard and plugin section to resolve this issue.

Please advise us on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you have issue, you should generally ask your developer for help. If they aren't available, log in to your FTP accounts, go to wp-content/plugins/ and rename the folder `wp-live-chat-support` to anything else, e.g. `disable.wp-live-chat-support`. The plugin will be deactivated and you can log in to wordpress again. Then get a new developer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the plugin uses a function available in WordPress 4.4 and you probably have a lower version.

Now to get you out of trouble, you could use FTP to reach your site's files, navigate to `wp-content/plugins/` and rename the directory of the troublesome plugin. This would force it to be deactivated. Now you could update your WordPress version to the latest and greatest (I highly recommend this), and then your plugin should work without a hitch.

Comment: `get_rest_url()` has actually been added in WordPress 4.4, not 4.8.

Comment: You are right @swissspidy. My bad for relying on the internet and not checking the core.